# Assigning a variable with bracket notation throws error "equal symbol expected"

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'm attempting to call a string from a JSON source which **works** when called like so:

```
${item.promo_images["default"].url}
```

However whenever I put this inside a variable it throws an error message.

```
<c:set var="photo" value="${item.promo_images["default"].url}" />

${photo}
```

The error message reads:

> Cause: /WEB-INF/jsp/features/global/curated-article-list/feature.jsp
>   (line: 21, column: 58) equal symbol expected.

Is there some kind of problem with the way I'm assigning this variable? I'm able to assign variables using pure dot notation, but the reason I've had to brackets in this case is because JSP doesn't seem to like calling `${item.promo_images.default.url}` (Something to do with the word default?)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try it this way. <c:set var="photo" value="${item.promo_images['default'].url}" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closer at the syntax highlighting.

```
<c:set var="photo" value="${item.promo_images["default"].url}" />
```

The `"` character right before `default` ends the attribute value and `default` is itself interpreted as a new attribute. The error you got,

> equal symbol expected

basically tells that it expected to see a `=` between `default` and subsequent `"` as below.

```
<c:set var="photo" value="${item.promo_images[" default="].url}" />
```

However, that was clearly not your intent.

Use single quotes instead. No, it won't be interpreted as a `char` orso.

```
<c:set var="photo" value="${item.promo_images['default'].url}" />
```

As to why you couldn't use `${item.promo_images.default.url}`, that's because Java language identifiers such as `import`, `public`, `class`, `protected`, `instanceof`, `package`, `default`, `while`, etc..etc.. may not be used as identifiers in EL.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the detailed response. Silly mistake on my half!

Thanks for explaining why dot notation doesn't work too, that's quite helpful.